# Extension for VSCode to manage Changelist like PHP Storm does

Tags: visual-studio-code, add-on, changelist

I'm working to migrate from PHP Storm to the useful Open Source platform VSCode. But I can't find a feature I've used everyday on PHP Storm. Thanks to the Changelist, I can manage huge micro-editings, and when all are done I make single Commit for each Change List.
Is this possible on VSCode?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There was a [Feature Request for this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36472) in the VS Code repo and [a question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/agyzbv/is_there_an_existing_way_i_can_replicate/). Both without results.

Answer (score 6):

I was today searching for something similar and came across your question.

I also found this extension in my searches, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=koenigstag.git-changelists

It's quite recent by the release date and got an update not long ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, this extension provides very limited functionality. Some of the features I personally miss there: * shelving a diff list, * splitting changes done to a single file between multiple change lists.